# Делегирование конструкторов в теле другого конструктора

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор

Я знаю, что в с++ есть фича делегирования конструкторов и следующий код выведет 12 согласно порядку выполнения конструкторов.

```
class A
{
    int i;
    A(int i): i(i) 
    {
        cout << 1;
    }
    A(int i, int): A(i)
    {
        cout << 2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A(0,0);
}
```

Но что если я хочу тем же конструктором получить 21? То есть выполнить тело второго конструктора до того, как делегировать инициализацию первому? Я могу захотеть это сделать, например, если до инициализации мне понадобиться сделать какие-то многострочные расчеты, что-то типа:

```
A(int i, int)
{
    cout << 2;
    return A(i);
}
```

Есть ли способы это сделать, кроме как это какой-нибудь фабрикой?

Comment: *— Так что, получается, если положить орудие на бок, то можно стрелять из-за угла?... — Можно! но уставом не предусмотрено! (с) Анекдот*

Comment: Нет, этого сделать нельзя. При входе в тело конструктора инициализация должна быть уже завершенаю

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для таких нужд создают функции инициализаци или же просто продумывают порядок. Зачем Вам такой функционал? Как и где, а главное пригодится ли он Вам вообще?

Похожий вопрос есть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/can-i-call-a-constructor-from-another-constructor-do-constructor-chaining-in-c), там и про делегацию, и про инициализирующие функции